# Add coordinate axes to a 3D plot of concentric spheres

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I want to add coordinate axis to a figure of nested spheres.

I have the command.

```
Graphics3D[Table[{Opacity[.6], Specularity[White, 20], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r]}, 
{r, 1/2, 3, 1/2}], Boxed -> False]
```

Which reproduces the set of nested spheres

[image]

Now, I would need to add axes X, Y and Z

It would also be good to be able to label the spheres 1, 2, 3...

Thanks
Edit: and to do something similar to this picture?

[image]

Comment: Add `, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}` for the axes. You can take a look at `Inset` for the labels.

Comment: `SphericalPlot3D[{1, 2, 3}, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 3 Pi/2},  Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.6], Specularity[White, 20]]]`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the documentation of [`SphericalPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html) you can find:

```
SphericalPlot3D[{1, 2, 3}, {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 3 Pi/2}]
```

Thus, you can modify it a little:

```
r = {1, 2, 3};
col = Hue@.5;
opts = {Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False};
spheres = SphericalPlot3D[Evaluate@r, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 3 Pi/2}, 
  Evaluate@opts, PlotStyle -> (Directive[Opacity@(1/#), col] & /@ r)];
(*axes and labels*)
al = Graphics3D[{Style[Text[#, RotateLeft@#2], Bold, 15] & @@@ 
  Thread[{{"X", "Y", "Z"}, RotateRight[{Max@r + Max@r/10, 0, 0}, #] & /@ {0, 1, 2}}], 
  Inset[Style[#, Bold, 20], {(Sqrt@2)/2 #, 0, (Sqrt@2)/2 #}] & /@ r}, 
  PlotRange -> Max@r, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}];
filling[{rmin_, rmax_}] := ParametricPlot3D[{r*{0, -1 Sin[t], Cos[t]}, 
  r*{Sin[t], 0, Cos[t]}}, {r, rmin, rmax}, {t, 0, Pi}, 
  Evaluate@opts, PlotStyle -> (Directive[EdgeForm[], Opacity@.75, col])];
Show[{al, spheres, filling[{0, Min@r}], filling[r[[2 ;; 3]]]}]
```

[image]

---

**Edit:**

It's now *easier* to chose where to place the axes labels:

```
r = {1, 2, 3};
col = Hue@.5;
opts = {Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False};
spheres = SphericalPlot3D[Evaluate@r, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 3 Pi/2}, 
  Evaluate@opts, PlotStyle -> (Directive[Opacity@(1/#), col] & /@ r)];
(*axes and labels*)
al = Graphics3D[{Style[Text[#, RotateLeft@#2], Bold, 15] & @@@ 
  {{Subscript[S, x], {Max@r + .5, 0, 0}}, 
   {Subscript[S, x], {0, Max@r + .5, 0}}, 
   {Subscript[S, x], {0, 0, -Max@r - .5}}}, 

  Inset[Style[#, Bold, 20], {(Sqrt@2)/2 #, 0, (Sqrt@2)/2 #}] & /@ r}, 
  PlotRange -> Max@r, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}];
filling[{rmin_, rmax_}] := ParametricPlot3D[{r*{0, -1 Sin[t], Cos[t]}, 
  r*{Sin[t], 0, Cos[t]}}, {r, rmin, rmax}, {t, 0, Pi}, 
  Evaluate@opts, PlotStyle -> (Directive[EdgeForm[], Opacity@.75, col])];
Show[{al, spheres, filling[{0, Min@r}], filling[r[[2 ;; 3]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This looks very good, lots of thanks. However I've written in the Axes "S_x","S_y" and "S_z" meanwhile the label for S_x is easy to recognize, when printing it's hard to see the other labels cause the background is not white. I would like to write the label (in your plot the Z) in the other extreme and the lift the label X a litle bit

Comment: @user10712 check the edit.

Answer (score 11):

```
options = {Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True,  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.6], Specularity[White, 20]], ImageSize -> 500};
SphericalPlot3D[{1, 2, 3}, {t, 0, Pi}, {p , 0, 3 Pi/2},  Evaluate@options]
```

[image]

or

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]} # & /@ {1, 2, 3}, 
  {v, 0, Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Evaluate@options, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x y > 0 || y > 0]]
```

or

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   Contours -> {1, 2, 3}, Evaluate[options /. PlotStyle -> ContourStyle],
   BoundaryStyle -> None, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x y > 0 || y > 0]]
```

or

```
Show[RevolutionPlot3D[{# Cos[t], # Sin[t]}, {t, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {v, Pi/2, 2 Pi},
     Evaluate@options] & /@ {3, 2, 1}]
```