# drawing core-shell structure

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I am pretty new in Mathematica drawing. I am trying to draw a core-shell structure, it means a core sphere with a shell sphere, like this

[image]

It can be in 2D or preferentially in 3D. Does someone can help me?

Comment: I tried the commands ParametricPlot3D[] and Sphere[], but they do not work. I want to do just a draw (core-shell structure) like in the link.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate?

Comment: Somewhat close: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47713/add-coordinate-axes-to-a-3d-plot-of-concentric-spheres

Comment: [Also similar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41985/862)

Comment: Coisa antiga em colega

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Show[RegionPlot3D[1 <= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 3 && (y >= x Sin[Pi/2] || y < -x Sin[Pi/2]),   
                  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 100], 
     Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: To avoid the blurry edges in the region plot, see [this nice method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48530/484).

Comment: @RahulNarain Thanks! That's very nice.

Answer (score 4):

```
SetOptions[{SphericalPlot3D, ParametricPlot3D}, Mesh -> None];

fun = {r {0, -Sin[t], Cos[t]}, r {Sin[t], 0, Cos[t]}};

p1 = SphericalPlot3D[{2, 2.5}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 1.5 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[Green, Opacity[0.7], Specularity[White, 20]]];

p2 = ParametricPlot3D[fun, {r, 2, 2.5}, {t, 0, Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[Green, Opacity[0.7], Specularity[White, 20]]];

p3 = SphericalPlot3D[{1.5, 1.99}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 1.5 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.7], Specularity[White, 20]]];

p4 = ParametricPlot3D[fun, {r, 1.5, 1.99}, {t, 0, Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.7], Specularity[White, 20]]];

p5 = SphericalPlot3D[{1, 1.48}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.7], Specularity[White, 20]]];

Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

```
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> Front]
```

[image]

```
 Grid[{{

   Show[p3, p4, p5, ClipPlanes -> {{-1, 1, 0, 1}},
    Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 400],

   Show[p3, p4, p5, ClipPlanes -> {{0, 0, -1, 0}},
    Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 400]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you a lot! that is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

```
 p = N@Table[  { Cos[x], 0, Sin[x]}, {x, Pi/2, -Pi/2, -Pi/200}];
 Show[ 
      {
     SphericalPlot3D[ 1 , {t, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 3 Pi/2}, Axes -> False, Mesh -> False],
     Graphics3D@{{Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1/2]},
                 Polygon[ p],
                 Polygon@(RotationTransform[-Pi/2, {0, 0, 1}]@p)
         }} , Boxed -> False ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is adapted from 3D solid modeling thick cylindrical shell done before (also ref. Mma site). Here it generates volume between two concentric spherical shells separately in three modes, for any desired choice. Hope it may be suitable.

```
 1. sweeps along parallels... t
 2. sweeps along meridians ...v ,or,
 3. dilates along shell normal, sphere expands or shrinks...a
```

[image: Thick Spherical Shell & Core]

ThickShell[a_, t_, v_] = a {Cos[t] Cos[v], Sin[t], Cos[t] Sin[v]};
(*  GLNarasimham SolidModelingThickShell.nb *)
Manipulate[
 Row[{ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] Cos[u], Sin[u], Cos[u] Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 
     2 Pi}, {u, -1.5, 1.5}, ImageSize -> 300, ViewPoint -> {3, 1, 2}],
    ParametricPlot3D[ThickShell[a, t, v], {v, 0, 2 Pi}, {a, 1, 1.6}, 
    Mesh -> {18, 4}, ImageSize -> 300, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1.8, 1.8}, {-2, 2}, {-1.8, 1.8}}, 
    ViewPoint -> {3, 1, 2}], 
   ParametricPlot3D[ThickShell[a, t, v], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {a, 1, 1.6}, 
    Mesh -> {18, 4}, ImageSize -> 300, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1.8, 1.8}, {-2, 2}, {-1.8, 1.8}}, 
    ViewPoint -> {3, 1, 2}], 
   ParametricPlot3D[ThickShell[a, t, v], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    Mesh -> {18, 18}, ImageSize -> 300, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1.8, 1.8}, {-2, 2}, {-1.8, 1.8}}, 
    ViewPoint -> {3, 1, 2}]}], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/5}, {v, 0, 2 Pi, 
  Pi/10}, {a, 1, 1.6, .05}]