# Rotate a region about z-azis

Tags: plotting

I learned how to do this:

```
Show[RevolutionPlot3D[{5 Cos[t], 5 Sin[t]},
  {t, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {\[Theta], 0, 3 Pi/2}],
 RevolutionPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t]},
  {t, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {\[Theta], 0, 3 Pi/2}]]
```

But I would like to show the region between the two surfaces. Can someone show me how?

Comment: You might want to look at `ParametricRegion[]`.

Comment: related Q/As: [Plotting semi-hollow spheres](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57434/125) , [Filling between spheres in SphericalPlot3D](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41985/filling-between-two-spheres-in-sphericalplot3d),  [3D plot of concentric spheres](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47713/add-coordinate-axes-to-a-3d-plot-of-concentric-spheres)

Answer (score 4):

For this specific example (concentric spheres of radius 1 and 5 with "bite" out of it), perhaps easiest:

```
Quiet@RegionPlot3D[
  1 < x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 25 && -Pi < ArcTan[y, x] < Pi/2, {x, -6, 
   6}, {y, -6, 6}, {z, -6, 6}, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Background -> Black]
```

[image]

Comment: What are you suppressing with `Quiet`? I tried to evaluate your expression without it, and it did not generate any messages.

Comment: @MarcoB 0/0 indeterminate for arctan warning...

Comment: What version of MMA are you using? I am on v 10.1 on Win7-64 and I did not receive any warnings even without the `Quiet`. Interesting... Thanks for getting back to me anyway!

Comment: @MarcoB "10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"