# How to visualize earth's core using Mathematica?

Tags: visualization

Is there a way to visualize the earth's core using Mathematica's volume rendering technique? Can someone who has looked at the feature provide an example for doing the visualization?

[image]

Possible add this to a manipulate so the crust opens up to reveal the inside.

The basic layers look like:

[image]

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59771/drawing-core-shell-structure?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47713/add-coordinate-axes-to-a-3d-plot-of-concentric-spheres

Comment: @Kuba I have added a picture from kids book. It is just to explain the thing to a child in 3D.

Comment: @CarlLange that would work but is there a way to stick the crust as well. A real image of a surface.

Comment: @user13892 then also related are: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/how-to-make-a-3d-globe and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60427/how-to-make-a-3d-topographic-globe

Comment: @CarlLange Is there a way to give it 3D texture like `mountain = Entity["Mountain", "MountEverest"]; surface = GeoElevationData[GeoDisk[mountain, Quantity[3, "Miles"]]]; ListPlot3D[Reverse[surface], MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 30, 
 ImageSize -> Large, ColorFunction -> Automatic]`. But from far way since i want it for the entire earth. With possible of scaling parameters since it would be hard to see the texture at that scale.

Comment: @user13892 Does this answer do what you're looking for? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134492/57593
My apologies, but I do not have the time to help you with a real answer, which is why I'm posting all these links in the hopes that they help you or someone else :)